# Type error when trying to extend a list in Python

Tags: python, list, append, python-2.x, extend

I need to understand why :

```
years = range(2010,2016)
years.append(0)
```

is possible, returning :

```
[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,0]
```

and

```
years = range(2010,2016).append(0)
```

or

```
years = [0].extend(range(2010,2016))
```

doesn't work ?

I understand that it is a type error from the message I got. But I'd like to have a bit more explanations behind that.

Comment: Your last line basically does this: Set up an anonymous list `[0]`, then `extend()` that list with the result of `range()`, store the result of `extend()` (which is `None`) in `years`, and then **throw away** that list, because it was never bound to a name.

Comment: You should really show the actual error you get. Either *both* examples produce a `TypeError` (using Python 3), or neither does (Python 2) but you end up with `years` set to `None`. Which one of the two actually happens? Can you supply the full traceback?

Comment: This version of the question is 2.x-specific, as `range` returns a `list` in 2.x, but a special object in 3.x. The mentioned `TypeError` presumably resulted from *subsequent use of* `years`. This is why it's important to provide a [mre] and a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing the result of the `list.append()` or `list.extend()` method; both alter the list *in place* and return `None`. They do *not* return the list object again.

Do not store the `None` result; store the `range()` result, *then* extend or append. Alternatively, use concatenation:

```
years = range(2010, 2016) + [0]
years = [0] + range(2010, 2016)
```

Note that I'm assuming you are using Python 2 (your first example would not work otherwise). In Python 3 `range()` doesn't produce a list; you'd have to use the `list()` function to convert it to one:

```
years = list(range(2010, 2016)) + [0]
years = [0] + list(range(2010, 2016))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`append` and `extend` operations on lists do not return anything (return just `None`). That is why `years` is not the list you expected.

Answer (score 0):

*In Python 3* `range` returns an instance of the range class and not a list. If you want to manipulate the result of `range` you need a list, so:

```
years = list(range(2010,2016)) 
years.append(2016)
```

Finally, (and similarly to the append above) extend operates on the list you're calling it from rather than returning the new list so:

```
years = list(range(2010,2016))
years.extend( list(range(2016,2020)))
```

*While Python 2's *`range`* function *does* return a list, the above code will still work fine in Python 2*

Hope this helps!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've adjusted my explanation to reflect your above point - Please re-evaluate as I think you have read an old version of my answer -- I did not suggest `years = list(range(2010, 2016)).append(0)` was correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please re-read my answer - I'm not storing the value of either of those.

Comment: my apologies; my mobile phone view of the code in your answer made it look like you did (the lines looked wrapped around rather than separate).