# List append() in for loop raises exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, for-loop, append

In Python, trying to do the most basic append function to a list with a loop:
Not sure what I am missing here:

```
a = []
for i in range(5):    
    a = a.append(i)
```

returns:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Not `a=append(i)`. Just `a.append(i)`.

Comment: And another dupe (possibly less canonical, but more helpful for this particular question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/31734042/748858)

Comment: Depending on what you exactly want to do, you can also create the same list with list comprehension. 

a = [x for x in range(5)]

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The `list.append` function does not return any value(but `None`), it just adds the value to the list you are using to call that method.

In the first loop round you will assign `None` (because the no-return of `append`) to `a`, then in the second round it will try to call `a.append`, as `a is None` it will raise the Exception you are seeing

You just need to change it to:

```
a = []
for i in range(5):
    # change a = a.append(i) to    
    a.append(i)
print(a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`list.append` is what is called a *mutating or destructive* method, i.e. it will destroy or mutate the previous object into a new one(or a new state).

If you would like to create a new list based in one list without destroying or mutating it you can do something like this:

```
a=['a', 'b', 'c']
result = a + ['d']

print result
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print a
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

As a corollary only, you can mimic the `append` method by doing the following:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = a + ['d']

print a
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: It *does* return a value. It returns `None`.

Comment: a.append([i for i in range(5)])

Answer (score 15):

You don't need the assignment, `list.append(x)` will always append `x` to `a` and therefore there's no need te redefine `a`.

```
a = []
for i in range(5):    
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```

is all you need. This works because `list`s are mutable.

Also see the [docs on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 6):

No need to re-assign.

```
a=[]
for i in range(5):    
    a.append(i)
a
```