# not able to use append function with list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create list of factors using index.

```
 n =int(input())
 a=list()
 b=list()

 for i in range(1,n+1):
      for j in range(1,i+1):
          if i%j==0 :
              b= b.append(j)
      a=a.append(b)
 print(a)
```

getting error message as follow:

```
 10
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:/Projects/Chatbot/assign1.py", line 23, in <module>
 a=a.append(b)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: The problem is that you are redefining `a` on the line where you do `a=a.append(b)`. The call to `append()` returns None and you are assigning that to `a` so `a` no longer refers to a list.

Comment: @abccd the answers there explain the error in this post. This is a (the?) canonical duplicate for this kind of questions.

Comment: @abccd there you go: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41452819 That question is essentially the same as this one, yet it was still closed as a duplicate of the canonical question.

Comment: I like that question better, haha:)

Comment: Use list comprehension:                                                                                 
    n = int(raw_input('choose a number'))

    for i in range(1,n+1):
     a = [ j for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j==0 ]
    print 'a = ', a 

    # Example: n = 3 returns a =  [1, 3]