# Matplotlib - Error in plotting 2 values with same dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matrix, physics

```
def Hamiltonian(alpha,h):

    Sx = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
    Sy = np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
    Sz = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
    I  = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])

    H = -1*((alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sx,Sx),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sy,Sy),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sx),Sx))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sy),Sy))
       + (h*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sz),I)))

    return H
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100)
Hamiltonian(1,0.5).real
```

Which returns the following matrix (just inputting this for clarity in what I'm trying to do below)
[image]

After defining Hamiltonian I want to look for entropy as a function of the h parameter. The physics behind the code does not matter for this type of question.

```
# von Neumann entropy as a function of h and beta - Complete
# Definition of a mixed state: [Thermal Density Matrix used]
h = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)
beta = 2
for i in range(h.size):
    H = Hamiltonian(1.0, h[i] )
    rho_thermal = expm(-1.0 * beta * H)
    tr = np.trace(rho_thermal)
    rho_thermal = rho_thermal / tr
    np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100)
    eigvals_rho_thermal, eigvecs_rho_thermal = LA.eigh(rho_thermal)
    # Entropy
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(eigvals_rho_thermal.size):
        s += -1.0 * (eigvals_rho_thermal[i] * np.log(eigvals_rho_thermal[i]))
    print(s)
plt.plot(h,s)
```

My question is why do i get the following error:
[image]

My code returns 25 values for s and 25 for h why will it not plot them?

Comment: No, `s` is a single float value, in this case the entropy of the Hamiltonian with h=2.4.

Comment: But how do I rectify my issue by plotting the corresponding s for each h? Thank you by the way I see what you mean

Comment: You may append each `s` to a list and `plot(h, list_of_s)`.

Comment: How would I construct such a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452819/list-append-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value of `s` you obtain in each loopstep somewhere to be able to plot each `s` for each `h` later on. In general you may simplify your code a bit and use a function instead of a for-loop.
Here is how I would do it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import expm

def Hamiltonian(alpha,h):

    Sx = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
    Sy = np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
    Sz = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
    I  = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])

    H = -1*((alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sx,Sx),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(Sy,Sy),I))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sx),Sx))
       + (alpha*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sy),Sy))
       + (h*np.kron(np.kron(I,Sz),I)))

    return H

# von Neumann entropy as a function of h and beta - Complete
# Definition of a mixed state: [Thermal Density Matrix used]
def get_entropy(beta, h, alpha=1.0):
    H = Hamiltonian(alpha, h)
    rho_thermal = expm(-1.0 * beta * H)
    tr = np.trace(rho_thermal)
    rho_thermal = rho_thermal / tr
    eigvals_rho_thermal, eigvecs_rho_thermal = np.linalg.eigh(rho_thermal)
    # Entropy
    s = -np.sum(eigvals_rho_thermal*np.log(eigvals_rho_thermal))
    return s

h = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)
beta = 2    
s = [get_entropy(beta, hi) for hi in h]
plt.plot(h,s)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for thank you very much