# Python append to list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains list of words.

Example:

```
[['A','B','C'],['D'],['E']]
```

To implement this i have create an empty list of list of size 4.

```
list1=[list()] *4
```

and then tried append element one by one.

```
list1[0].append('A')
list1[0].append('B')
list1[0].append('C')
list1[1].append('D')
list1[2].append('E')
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
```

Expected was:

```
[['A','B','C'],['D'],['E']]
```

Comment: Can you not use a for loop as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452819/list-append-in-for-loop

Comment: `print([id(x) for x in list1])` will show they are all the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that here :

```
list1=[list()] *4
```

you are making copies of the same list object.  You are essentially adding the elements to the same list every time.

To fix:

```
list1=[[] for i in range(3)]


list1[0].append('A')
list1[0].append('B')
list1[0].append('C')
list1[1].append('D')
list1[2].append('E')
```

Which gives your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization method you used creates a list of four pointers that all point to the same list. You shouldn't use the asterisk operator in this case.