# In Python, I assigned an empty list to another list to print and for some reason it prints the last element of the list

Tags: python

instead of printing 12359
it prints 9 for some reason

### code

```
  b=["12","3","5","9"]
  b1=[]
  for x in range(0,len(b)):
      b1=b[x]

  print(b1,end='')
```

### output

```
9
```

Comment: You have to indent print(b1) as well, so it will be executed in the loop. This will print every number in a single line though. If you want to have them all in one line, you will to add them to an output string.

Comment: I am new to python so i dont understand what you meant

Comment: Everything with the same indent (number of spaces before the code) as `b1=b[x]` will get executed inside the loop. To create a list or string, see my more detailed answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List append() in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452819/list-append-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to concatenate the elements of b into a string,
just try:

```
b = ["12", "3", "5", "9"]
b1 = ''.join(b)
```

Explanation:

```
Help on built-in function join:

join(iterable, /) method of builtins.str instance
    Concatenate any number of strings.
    
    The string whose method is called is inserted in between each given string.
    The result is returned as a new string.
    
    Example: '.'.join(['ab', 'pq', 'rs']) -> 'ab.pq.rs'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate all strings, you need to use a string for `b1`:

```py
b = ["12", "3", "5", "9"]
b1 = ""
for x in range(0, len(b)):
    b1 += b[x]
print(b1)
```

Comment: so why did u use b1=" " instead of b1=[ ]? is there a reason why?

Comment: if you want to print "12359" you need a string, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

b1 is not a list. Its is a string. If you to have a list, do this:

```
 b=["12","3","5","9"]
  b1=[]
  for x in range(0,len(b)):
      b1.append(b[x])

print(b1) # Prints the exact same as b.
```

If you want an output string, you should add it to an empty string like so:

```
 b=["12","3","5","9"]
  b1=""
  for x in range(0,len(b)):
      b1 += b[x]
```